# Python: How do I install packages within my package or repository?

Tags: python, version-control, package

My program requires specific versions of several python packages. I don't want to have to require the user to specifically install the specific version, so I feel that the best solution is to simply install the package within the source repository, and to distribute it along with my package.

What is the simplest way to do this?

(Please be detailed - I'm familiar with pip and easy_install, but they don't seem to do this, at least not by default).

Comment: What platforms does it work on? How are the users supposed to use it?

Comment: @Wang: All platforms. Users won't even know it's there.

Answer (score 1):

Go for [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).  Life will be much easier.  MUCH easier.  Basically, it allows you to create specific python environments as needed.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get back to this before.  virtualenv creates a new environment with its own bin and library directories, and installs all the specifics of python you need in that environment.  Having created the envirronment, you can package it up.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed two ways to get this done.

I usually use buildout (see a post by Jacob from Django: http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/) - and have everything from django up installed locally at the project's environment, with pydev and django support. It's very easy since I have projects that use latest versions of open source software and others that use specific versions of the same packages.

Another alternative is, as Charlie says, the [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv),which is designed to do just that. Many people recommend it, I've never used it myself as I'm happy with buildout.